# Thermal rise for a dual diode package (common cathode)

Tags: diodes, thermal, dual

How would I calculate it when both diodes in a D2PAK are used in continuous current of 2.5 A with an ~40 C/W on the graph below ?

https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stth2003-956882.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends on the PCB. Thermal calculations for SMD parts are *very* much just estimates. Often not very good ones.

Comment: How would you calculate it if only one diode were being used.

Comment: @Andyaka Not sure. 40 C/W * 2 W ?

Comment: @kellogs Great. This works for any number of power dissipating sources in the package. Just add their power together to calculate temperature rise.

Answer (score 1):

Before or after it fails?

If your assumptions are correct then the junction temperature will (typically) be around the absolute maximum 175 degrees C even with non-elevated 25 degrees C ambient temperature. That is **far** too high for reliable operation, let alone additional allowance for a warm environment.

Look at the Vf curve for typical forward voltage (for each diode) and multiply by the current and add the two powers, then multiply by the thermal resistance. If your current is *anything* but smooth DC with no ripple then the RMS current, and thus the heating, will be worse. And, of course, those are typical figures, not worst-case.

Thermal resistance in the datasheet is based on a specific physical construction (often you can find the test board layout and dimensions) and your real situation might be worse or better.